# Redirect From Subdomain to Folder Without URL Change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to img.cetinblog.com act like cetinblog.com/feedimg/ . I use code but url is changing. I don't want to any changes on url.

htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} img.cetinblog.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cetinblog.com/feedimg/$1 [L]
```

Where is the problem ? Thank you.

Edit:
http://img.cetinblog.com/zombi.jpg should redirect http://cetinblog.com/feedimg/zombi.jpg but I have some problems.

Comment: Are both domains sharing same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: I don't know excatly however when I sent to mail server for pointing subdomain to folder, they said ; we can not do that but you can do with htaccess. I think it should be.

Comment: shouldn't this be done the other way round. Requests going to http://cetinblog.com/feedimg/ to be requesting from http://img.cetinblog.com/

Comment: OK thank you. So I should find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.cetinblog\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!feedimg/).+)$ /feedimg/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Provide details what's not working? Are you getting 404 or 500?

Comment: 404. http://img.cetinblog.com/zombi.jpg should redirect http://cetinblog.com/feedimg/zombi.jpg . you can check. Obviously it is not same document root.

Comment: Yes that's why I asked that question before posting answer. This won't be possible unless you have control over server and whether you can enable `mod_proxy`.